# Facing Login Issue of Local Accounts user with OpenId Connect in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, openconnect

[image][image][image]1. I am trying to implement SSO through OpenIdConnect with AzureB2C but was facing some problem during login of Local Account Users with OpenId Connect which was configured on Azure B2C.

2.When i run our user flow and try to login with local account user credentials then it says user does not exist although i am able to login email default provider.

3.Since I am new to Azure and OpenID Connect so can you please guys help me out so that i can login Local Account Users with Open Id Connect in Azure B2C and how can i proceed further so that i can implement SSO with OpenIdConnect and Azure B2C?

**What i have tried till now?**

1. Created OpenId Connect as a Identity Provider.
2. Create app in app registrations.
3. Created a User Flow and selected both Local Account as well
   previously created openid connect identity provider.
4. Try to run configured user flow but failed to login.

Images with order are attached

[image]

Comment: You should follow this [B2C Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-add-identity-providers). Try it and let me know if you encounter any issue.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil. By default, the user object for a local user account isn't linked to that for the external user (OpenID Connect IdP) account? Are you expecting this to be so?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thanks for the suggestion but the thing is that i have already followed this link. 
Challenge is that when we are login with local account user credentials with Identity provider as OpenId Connect eg.nikhil@live.com it asks me the social account password.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Yes we are trying this only can you please guide us how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an Azure AD B2C custom policy sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account) that demonstrates how to link a social account with a local account.